# Set up serial pipe between VMware Linux guest and Windows host

Tags: linux, windows, vmware, serial-port

I am using VMware Workstation 12 Player. My host is Windows 10, my guest is Fedora 22.

I want to set up a COM port between the host and guest. The reason is I have an app running in Windows that needs to talk to an app that only runs in Linux.

I followed the instructions posted on VMware website. To summarize:

In the VM:

- Added a named pipe called `\\.\pipe\com12`, I have also tried `\\.\pipe\com_12`.
- Settings are `This end is the server.` and `The other end is an application.`, which I think is accurate.
- The port shows up when the VM boots up as `Serial Port 2`.

In Windows (host):

- I used com0com to set up a pair of named pipes in Windows. I have COM10 linked to COM12. Nothing else is using the ports.

On Windows I opened TeraTerm, set it up to use COM10 (but I have also tried COM12), set baudrate to 115200, parity is 'none', 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no flow control.

On Linux I opened cutecom, set it up to use ttyS2 (Serial Port 2, right?), and matched all other settings.

I tried sending characters from Windows to Linux and the other way around, but I don't see anything. What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I figured it out. Since I was using com0com, I didn't need to make a named pipe. This is the process I followed:

1. Set up a pair of COM ports in Windows using com0com. For me the pair as COM10 and COM12.
2. In VMware add a serial port:

   - Under `Connection` select `Use physical serial port`, and select COM10.

Now in Windows I open RealTerm and connect to COM12. In Fedora I open Cutecom and connect to ttyS2. They can now communicate!